# Java EMF DataBinding EOperation

Tags: java, eclipse, emf

I need to bind the value returned by a certain EOperation that I've defined in my model.

Usually I perform databind using FeaturePath and Literals, but I've always done that with attributes, never with EOperation.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can use yourModel.Property.name.yourProperty()

Comment: Sorry, this can't help me. I need to bind the return value of an "EOperation". Binding properties already works.